# Sending specific words to webhook

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm trying to make an agent that can give me details about movies.

For example, the user says "Tell me about (movie-name)", which sends a post request to my API with the (movie-name) which then returns the response.

However, I don't understand how to grab the movie name from the user's speech without creating a movieName entity with a list of all the movies out there. I just want to grab the next word the user says after "tell me about" and store it as a parameter. How do I go about achieving that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you must create a movieName entity, but you do not need to create a list of all movies.  Maybe you are experienced with Alexa which requires a list of suggested values, but in api.ai you don't need to do that.

I find that api.ai is not very good at figuring out which words are part of a free-form entity like movieName, but hopefully adding enough user expressions will help it with that.

edit: the entity I was thinking of is '@sys.any' but maybe it would be better to use a list of movie names with the 'automated expansion' feature.  I haven't tried that, but it sounds like the way that Alexa's custom slots work, which is actually a lot more flexible (just using the list as a guideline) then people seem to think.

Comment: Could you point me in the right direction regarding free-form entities?